# Как получить данные со страницы через скрипт для сайта

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, cors

Пытаюсь со своего сайт *запарсить* [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), через скрипт на сайте, через `fetch()`, получаю ошибку:
`Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1/' from origin 'https://www.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`
Должно выдать html код со страницы

Comment: что вам непонятно в приведенном тексте сообщения об ошибке?

Comment: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: А чего вам нужно от кода странички гугела?

Comment: Не понятно, как это исправить - это ошибка в принципе про cors

Comment: А страница гугл - это как пример где выдает такую ошибку

Comment: Никак не исправить, если запрашиваемый сайт не разрешит. Это не ошибка, а следствие политики безопасности. Но если немного (а может и много) поизощряться, то данные вытянуть таки можно.